# 'where' operator: Failed to resolve column or scalar expression named '<column name>'

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, heartbeat

Getting error `'where' operator: Failed to resolve column or scalar expression named 'AgeofOldestMissingRequiredUpdate'` while running heartbeat query from Azure portal

Comment: The error tells that you are trying to reference a column that is not present in the table.
Please share the whole query.

Comment: Just so that it is put here, make sure to have the correct values to the headers - `X-Api-Key` and `appId`

Answer (score 0):

> 'where' operator: Failed to resolve column or scalar expression named 'column name'

This error can be the result of a number of different scenarios. You haven't posted your query, but I achieved the same error with a query like

```
MyTable
| Project Column1, Column2
| where Column3 == "Value"
| Take 100
```

In my case there was a 2nd error:

```
The name '<column>' does not refer to any known column, table, variable or function.
```

`MyTable`s structure did indeed contain the column!

```
MyTable
|- Column1
|- Column2
|- Column3
```

**Solution**

I updated my query so that the `project` clause contained the column named in the `where` clause:

```
MyTable
| Project Column1, Column2, Column3
| where Column3 == "Value"
| Take 100
```

Then I could run my query successfully. :-)

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76567748/15740725) for another possible solution. When performing `union` on multiple tables,

> if a column appears in multiple tables and has multiple types, it has a corresponding column for each type in the union's result. This column name is suffixed with a '_' followed by the origin column type.

So the original column name won't be present in the unioned result set, resulting in this error.