# Azure Log Analytics - Unable to use ItemCount in union result

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to write a Kusto query that will union `myUnion` with `AppTraces` logs. All works until I declare `ItemCount` column as part of `myUnion` results. You can do this with other columns, e.g. `TimeGenerated`.

The error returned is

> 'project' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'ItemCount'

```
let countRequests = 5;
let myUnion =  union  (print
            TimeGenerated = now(),
            Message = "MyMessage",
            ItemCount = countRequests);
AppTraces
| union myUnion
| project
    TimeGenerated,
    ErrorMessage = Message,
    ItemCount
| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

Possible workaround: I can name `myUnion.ItemCount` something else and coalesce, but I'd preferably like to use the built-in `ItemName`.

Comment: Odd. The results include `ItemCount_long` and `ItemCount_int`, but no `ItemCount`. However, if I run the same query just replacing `myUnion.ItemCount` alias with `x`, I do get `ItemCount` in the results. There must be some strange hidden behavior with `ItemCount`.

Comment: you should read [the documentation for the `union` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#parameters) - specifically look at the part detailing the `kind` parameter: "*...This means that if a column appears in multiple tables and has multiple types, it has a corresponding column for each type in the union's result. This column name is suffixed with a '_' followed by the origin column type.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have a conflicting column named `ItemCount` with a different datatype in your table named `AppTraces`.

what does the following return?

```
let countRequests = 5
;
let myUnion =  print TimeGenerated = now(),
    Message = "MyMessage",
    ItemCount = countRequests
;
AppTraces
| union myUnion
| getschema
```

if you see two columns with different datatypes, for example `ItemCount_int` and `ItemCount_long` - you'll want to align the data types (e.g. by switching to `let countRequests = int(5)`)

Comment: Thanks that's it! `AppTraces.ItemCount` is `int`, while `myUnion.ItemCount` was `long`. This generated 2 columns in the result set, `ItemCount_int` and `ItemCount_long`. I needed to use `toint`, possibly since the actual value of `myUnion.ItemCount` is not a constant.

Comment: By the way, I think this behavior is confusing and unintuitive. I would prefer implicit conversion, or an error if implicit conversion is impossible (like sql), rather than changing the columns under my feet